# How to enable automatic indentation in python.el from fgallina

Tags: python, emacs

I have installed the python package in emacs which downloads the python.el from https://raw.github.com/fgallina/python.el/master/python.el

I would like to have automatic indentation ie when I write `def a():` and press `RET` it should automatically indent with a TAB. However I have to manually press TAB for indenting ? How do I enable it ?

This was the default behaviour in the python.el avalaible from https://launchpad.net/python-mode

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: from  https://launchpad.net/python-mode you got python-mode.el, not python.el. The command is py-indent-line, mapped onto TAB. You may use it parallel with python.el; both mode should not conflict, as python-mode.el commands start with "py-".

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I now have both python-mode and python installed from melpa. However when I open my python file and type M-x describe-mode I only see the python.el in the major mode and not the python-mode.el also. How do I correct it ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a fork of GNU/Emacs' python .el. "This is a home-brew python-mode with some excerpts from GNU/Emacs’ python.el." Something is not working, because line 585 to 1070 of the .el file is about indentation ;) . Note, that this version is not tested for Emacs 24. Try: M-x describe-mode to see if you are actually using python mode. Is there an error message at startup? Have you added the file to the path? This should be in your .emacs file.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/my/path/to/el/")
(require 'python)
```

From 
http://emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs

"There are three implementations of a Python mode for Emacs: python.el and python-mode.el.

ProgrammingWithPythonDotEl – python.el comes with GNU Emacs.

ProgrammingWithPythonModeDotEl – python-mode.el comes from Python.

ProgrammingWithPythonDotElGallina? – https://github.com/fgallina/python.el Fabián Ezequiel Gallina’s new implementation of python.el (part of Emacs trunk as of revno 108614)"